# Instagram Get Access Token from Code in PHP

Tags: instagram

Following php code is not working for me to get access token 
In client id and secret key, i have replaced with my real client id and key.

```
<?php
$client_id = 'MY CLIENT ID';
$client_secret = 'MY CLIENT SECRET';
$redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/instagram/demo.php';
$scope = 'basic+likes+comments+relationships';

$url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=$client_id&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&scope=$scope&response_type=code";

if(!isset($_GET['code']))
{
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Login With Instagram</a>';
}
else
{
    $code = $_GET['code'];

$apiData = array(
  'client_id'       => $client_id,
  'client_secret'   => $client_secret,
  'grant_type'      => 'authorization_code',
  'redirect_uri'    => $redirect_uri,
  'code'            => $code
);

$apiHost = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiHost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($apiData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($apiData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($jsonData);
$user = @json_decode($jsonData); 

echo '<pre>';
print_r($user);
exit;
}
?>
```

Above code always return false.. I can not figure out why this is not working.

Anybody debug this code and let me know what is problem in my code?

Answer (score 3):

Since it's https already so you need to put this on your code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

It's not about your redirect uri is in local or not. It's because SSL_VERIFYPEER is not set in your curl option

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a few issues with your code. For one it seems like your redirect_uri is localhost. Obviously localhost to Instagram is their own servers. You need to provide a FQDN/world accessible url.

Also from http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php the code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($apiData));
```

Should simple be

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but you need change

`$redirect_uri = 'your site addres (not localhost)';`

Example:

```
$client_id        = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
$client_secret    = 'YOUR CLIENT SECRET';
$redirect_uri     = 'http://www.YOUR_SERVER.com/instagram/demo.php';
$scope            = 'basic+likes+comments+relationships';
```

If  you execute this script with this change you can obtain this result.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [access_token] => 'your_ID'.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [user] => stdClass Object
        (
            [username] => 'your username'
            [bio] => 
            [website] => 
            [profile_picture] => 'your url picture profile' 
            [full_name] => 
            [id] => 'your_ID'
        )

)
```