# Fetching data with the Instagram API via cron jobs

Tags: api, cron, instagram

I have this script the logs a user into Instagram much like the found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109463/instagram-get-access-token-from-code-in-php). Once the user is logged in and an access token is generated, the user is redirected to the `redirect_uri`, but with the `$_GET['code']` variable in the URL. Once the `redirect_uri` is loaded, a script is executed that loops thru an array of Instagram account ID's and gets info about each page. The problem is that the same code variable that's in the URL cannot be used more than once. Refreshing the page will not successfully get any info about the Instagram accounts because it needs to be unique.

So, here is my question: can the script that is executed once the `redirect_uri` is loaded be executed via crons? I'm not sure how a cron would log into Instagram. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can discard the `code` variable once the page is loaded, and only store and use the access token (in a database or file on server) to make API calls, which as of right now does not expire and can be re-used.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Lance Sorry for the delayed repsonse, I have a small API wrapper for PHP that handles this well, and could be pretty easily ported: https://github.com/cdbconcepts/InstaWrapper